# How to ignore files based on suffix in cloc..?

Tags: open-source, lines-of-code, cloc

It should be a trivial task but neither reading through the docs and man page nor googling brought up a solution to what I'm trying to achieve:

`cloc` is scanning our source tree and we want it to ignore all *.html and *.css files.

Is there some way to give `cloc` a list of file extensions to ignore..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the help , via `cloc --help`, gives:

```
--exclude-ext=<ext1>[,<ext2>[...]] 
Do not count files having the given file name extensions.
```

I tried

```
cloc <file(s)/dir(s)> --exclude-ext=html,css
```

and it worked as expected.